# How to reuse gradle-wrapper?

Tags: java, gradle, android-studio

All, I migrate from eclipse to android-studio for one month. the new build tool is annoying.

Every time I `git clone` a android-sample, need hours to download the its gradle-wrapper.

I found there're many version of gradle-wrapper

```
ninja@ninja ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists $ du -h  --max-depth=1
198M    ./gradle-2.2.1-all
176M    ./gradle-1.11-all
86M ./gradle-1.12-bin
85M ./gradle-2.0-bin
358M    ./gradle-1.12-all
186M    ./gradle-2.1-all
1.1G    .

ninja@ninja ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all $ du -h --max-depth=1
179M    ./2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo
179M    ./4ff8jj5a73a7zgj5nnzv1ubq0
358M    .
```

**Is there a easy way to build projects from github ?**

and why android-studio do not use my gradle?

```
ninja@ninja ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all $ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-09-08 10:40:39 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     e6cf70745ac11fa943e19294d19a2c527a669a53

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_67 (Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-24-generic i386
```

I tried android-studio's setting `use local gradle distribution` , and meet compile errors:

```
ninja@ninja ~/src/goshawk/13_GeexFinanceSource/Geexfinance $ gradle installDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/ninja/src/goshawk/13_GeexFinanceSource/Geexfinance/SlidingMenuLibrary/build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':SlidingMenuLibrary'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android-library']
```

> Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/ninja/src/goshawk/13_GeexFinanceSource/Geexfinance/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 5.884 secs
```

I need your help, any idea?

Comment: What compile errors?

Comment: @ScottBarta I paste the errors above, seems version not match. I couldn't find gradle-version in build.gradle, where the version is specified?

Answer (score 4):

From [gradle-wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) docs:

```
If you don't want any download to happen when your project is build via gradlew,
simply add the Gradle distribution zip to your version control at the location
specified by your wrapper configuration. A relative URL is supported - you can
specify a distribution file relative to the location of gradle-wrapper.properties 
file.
```

Basically, once you have the binaries `gradle-2.1-bin.zip` and the wrapper jar `gradle-wrapper.jar` you can simply move it around where ever you please with the correct `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `gradlew` executable.

The folder structure of your project will be:

```
Project1 -> gradlew or gradlew.bat (wrapper executable)
            gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-2.1-bin.zip
                                 gradle-wrapper.jar
                                 gradle-wrapper.properties
```

The `gradlew` executable looks for `gradle-wrapper.jar` in `./gradle/wrapper/`

Here is an example of `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
# copy the distribution to the gradle/wrapper directory manually for the first run
# that way the distribution doesn't need to be checked into version control
distributionUrl=gradle-2.1-bin.zip
```

When running `./gradlew` in `Project1` it will extract to `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.1-bin/`

Just copy `Project1/gradle*` to `Project2/` to reuse the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and just now I fixed it!
In root `build.gradle` type

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2'
}
```

Also it can be useful to fix Gradle settings to recomended in the "Fix Gradle Settings" dialog. Or you can manually download `gradle-2.2-all.zip`, place it in `{project_dir}-gradle-wrapper` and run `gradlew.bat` in terminal.