# Gradle does not point to specified version

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am trying to upgrade the gradle wrapper version in my react-native android project.

I did not install gradle globally in my Mac, I just use the wrapper that comes with react-native, it was version 2.14.1. I want to use a library and it requires gradle 4.4+ and I followed the official tutorial. Off the bat, I got this [Issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1033#issuecomment-385271170).

I found that whenever I type `./gradlew -v` it will always refer to the `/Users/rexlow/.gradle/wrapper/dists` in my user directory, although I already did specify that I want to use `gradle-4.4-all.zip` which is the newer version. The zip file is now in my project wrapper folder, (I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376432/9049053))

As you can see from the image below, I tried to check for the gradle version but it will always show 2.14.1.

Then, I tried deleting the 2.14.1 gradle folder from `/Users/rexlow/.gradle/wrapper/dists` and run the version checking command again, and for heaven sake, it went on and download the 2.14.1 version because the folder wasn't there.

How can I altogether use a new gradle version in my project? Altering `gradle-wrapper.properties` does not work in my case. Let me know if you need to have a look at other files.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I see one odd thing, the `gradle` folder is into `app`, but I think it should be under the same folder as `.gradle`. Can you give a try a put gradle out of `app`?

Comment: @xiaomi My friend has the exact project structure (Windows 10) as mine, except that when he ran `./gradlew -v` inside the android folder, he gets version 4.4. We have the same Android Studio version.

Comment: I see 2 Gradle folder. One inside Android, one inside app. You should focus on the Gradle folder inside Android, not inside app

Comment: @xiaomi Excellence point! I obviously overlooked the other gradle folder lol.... I am able to run the project now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I added an answer so you can mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradle folder should be located inside `android` instead of `app`.